# push multiple arrays into an ordered array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have these three arrays:

```
const time = ["8n", "8n", "4n", "4n", "8n", "8n"];    
const note = [422, 303, 482, 419, 478, 467, 317, 343];    
const velocity = [0.57, 0.28, 0.35, 0.45, 0, 0.4, 0.53, 0.46, 0.48, 0.39];
```

How do I turn those into this, notice the matching indexes:

```
const part = [
  { time: "8n", note: 422, velocity: 0.57 },
  { time: "8n", note: 303, velocity: 0.28 },
  { time: "4n", note: 482, velocity: 0.35 }
];
```

The beginning array lengths of time, note and velocity will always be different, so part length should match the smallest of the beginning three.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please post what you've tried and where you're having issues. A potential answer is one line of code using [*Array.prototype.map*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.map), another might use [*reduce*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```js
const time = ["8n", "8n", "4n", "4n", "8n", "8n"];
const note = [422, 303, 482, 419, 478, 467, 317, 343];
const velocity = [0.57, 0.28, 0.35, 0.45, 0, 0.4, 0.53, 0.46, 0.48, 0.39];

const merge = (timeArr, noteArr, velocityArr) => {
    const length = Math.min(time.length, note.length, velocity.length);
    const ret = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        ret.push({
            time: timeArr[i],
            note: noteArr[i],
            velocity: velocityArr[i]
        });
    }

    return ret;
};

console.log(merge(time, note, velocity));
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
addEventListener('load', function(){
const time = ["8n", "8n", "4n", "4n", "8n", "8n"];    
const note = [422, 303, 482, 419, 478, 467, 317, 343];    
const velocity = [0.57, 0.28, 0.35, 0.45, 0, 0.4, 0.53, 0.46, 0.48, 0.39];
for(var i=0,part=[],l=time.length; i<l; i++){
  part.push({time:time[i], note:note[i], velocity:velocity[i]});
}
console.log(part);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the wanted parts of the arrays.

```js
const time = ["8n", "8n", "4n", "4n", "8n", "8n"];
const note = [422, 303, 482, 419, 478, 467, 317, 343];
const velocity = [0.57, 0.28, 0.35, 0.45, 0, 0.4, 0.53, 0.46, 0.48, 0.39];

const merge = (timeArr, noteArr, velocityArr) => timeArr
    .slice(0, Math.min(time.length, note.length, velocity.length))
    .map((time, i) => ({
        time,
        note: noteArr[i],
        velocity: velocityArr[i]
    }));

console.log(merge(time, note, velocity));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```